# how to use url in djangoframework

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I tried to Django crud operation get, post, delete, show method is working fine but the update method is not working because I tried to click the update button the update URL is not updated (**http://localhost:8000/show/4/update/4/**) how to handle this error and how to define the URL using Django.

**index.html**

```
<h1> Registration Form </h1>
<form action="post/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<h1>List of all user</h1>  
<table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
        {% for i in data %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ i.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ i.email}}</td>
          <td><a href="show/{{ i.id }}/">Edit</a></td>
          <td><a href="delete/{{ i.id }}/">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </table>
```

**Edit.html**

```
<h1> Update Form </h1>
<form action="update/{{ data.id }}/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label>Name</label> 
    <input type="textbox" name="name" value="{{ data.name }}"> 
    <label>Email</label> 
    <input type="textbox" name="email" value="{{ data.email }}"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import CrudOperation
from .forms import CrudForm

# Create your views here.
def get(request):
    form = CrudForm()
    data = CrudOperation.objects.all()
    return render(request,'index.html',{'form':form,'data':data})

def getId(request,id):
    form = CrudForm()
    data = CrudOperation.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request,'edit.html',{'form':form,'data':data})

def post(request):
    form = CrudForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    return HttpResponse('<h1>post Method</h1>')

def update(request,id):
    print(id)
    data = CrudOperation.objects.get(id=id)
    form = CrudForm(request.POST,instance=data)
    if(form.is_valid()):
        form.save()
    return HttpResponse('<h1>update method</h1>')

def delete(request,id):
    data = CrudOperation.objects.get(id=id)
    data.delete()
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Delete method</h1>')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from olcapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.get),
    url(r'^post/',views.post),
    url(r'^show/([0-9]+)/',views.getId),
    url(r'^update/([0-9]+)/',views.update),
    url(r'^delete/([0-9]+)/',views.delete),
]
```

How to fix this URL issue

Answer (score 1):

Don not hardcode url patterns so for this [name](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) your urls first.

```
   url(r'^update/([0-9]+)/',views.update,name='update'),
```

Now you can use the [{% url %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url) tag in your template like this:

```
form action="{% url 'update' data.id %}" method="POST">
```

Here in your `update` function you are not rendering `edit.html`.Change your view like this.

```
def update(request,id):
    print(id)
    data = CrudOperation.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST': # check first if the request is post
      form = CrudForm(request.POST,instance=data)
      if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponse('<h1>update method</h1>')
    else:
      form = CrudForm(instance=data)
   return render(request,'edit.html',{'data':data,'form':form})
```

Also if you are using django version 2+ use the [path](http://%20https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/#path) instead of url

Comment: I tried it but it's showing this error **Reverse for 'update' not found. 'update' is not a valid view function or pattern name.**

Comment: django 2.2.7 version

Comment: I have doubt Why use path .url is not supported in django 2.2.7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203126/discussion-between-hari-prasanth-and-arjun).

Answer (score 0):

A little edit for your index html:

```html
<h1> Registration Form </h1>
<form action="post/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<h1>List of all user</h1>  
<table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
        {% for i in data %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ i.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ i.email}}</td>
          <td><a href="/show/{{ i.id }}/">Edit</a></td>
          <td><a href="/delete/{{ i.id }}/">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </table>
```